# Don't rebuild webpack bundle if entry files didn't change

Tags: webpack

Consider we have a webpack config like this:

```
entry: {
    app: './main.js',
    lib: './vendor.js',   
}
```

The `vendor.js` file only consists of a bunch of requires to libraries from `node_modules`. 99% of the time I build the bundle(s) the output `lib.js` bundle is exactly the same.

Can I somehow tell webpack that if the `vendor.js` file didn't change (or preferrably some other custom condition like checking the modification date of `lib.js` and `package.json` to detect if I possibly have new versions of modules in `node_modules`) I **do not want** to rebuild the `lib.js` bundle? It takes a substantial amount of time on my CI server because of typescript transpliations etc.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I am aware Webpack only really knows if a file will be the same once it has already built it because so many factors can change the file contents. The modified date of a file really does not provide enough information to determine that it should not be built again so **I'd advise against it** or you'll probably end up breaking your builds at some point and leaving people confused.

However if you did feel the need to do this though you could if you wanted make your Webpack config dynamic and use [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/fs.html#fs.stat) to read `vendor.js` and then only add it as an entry if its changed. Something roughly like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var config = {
    entry: {
        app: './main.js'
    }
    ...
};

var stats = fs.statSync('./vendor.js');
if (new Date(stats.mtime).getTime() > process.env.LAST_VENDOR_BUILD_TIMESTAMP) {
    config.lib = './vendor.js';
    // Then save new Date().getTime() somewhere like a DB and
    // pass it in as LAST_VENDOR_BUILD_TIMESTAMP on next build.
}

module.exports = config;
```

As you can see the only way to solve your problem is that each and every build needs to have knowledge about previous builds to achieve this. This is undesired as your builds should be discrete and not care about previous build results.

Alternatively you should also try excluding some `node_modules` from the build if it is taking a really long time. I've not built typescript projects before but I exclude all of `node_modules` and my builds run much faster. Other than that, you shouldn't really mind your CI server being a little slow, at least it will be robust.